# Data Recovery from a Seagate Barracuda ST1000DM003 Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, data-recovery, sata

My desktop computer died today. I have important work saved on my desktop. I got the hard drive which I believe is in working condition. My hard drive specification is as follows:

**Seagate Barracuda ST1000DM003**

Is there any SATA to USB adapter available for this hard drive? If yes, what is the specification (cable no etc.)?
I also need a power supply to power the disk. But I am not sure what type of 
power cable would fit into my hard drive.

Comment: Yes, 3.5” SATA to USB 3 docking stations do exist

Comment: You beat me to it, @Ramhound! https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/USB-3-0-SATA-Hard-Drive-Dock-3-5-2-5-HDD-Docking-Station-Auto-Sleep-Touch-Button-/201292379709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Seagate Barracuda ST1000DM003 is a 1TB standard SATA 6.0Gb/s 3.5" drive. The products you'd want to look for are called "docking station" (larger devices, that hold the drive in place with a base or "adapter" (a simple cable) and both plug into USB on a host machine and provide the SATA interface as well as SATA power for the drive, so you don't need a seperate power adapter.

If you are frequently dumping drives from out-of-commission computers, I'd recommend the docking station, as it's slightly more convenient, but if this is something you do infrequently, probably just the adapter.

Verify your adapter or docking station support SATA 6.0 and USB3 and that the host USB port you are using is USB3 for maximum throughput. If you choose a docking station, verify that it supports 3.5" drives.

You will want to use a host machine that has sufficient space to copy the files off of the drive. You should avoid making writes to the drive if you suspect it is damaged (e.g. deleting unwanted files, renaming or moving files), instead copy only the desired files from the drive to the host machine then do any renaming, organization, or clean up afterward.